# how make this glass color shadow on photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shadows

i´m trie, but don´t make this shadow above.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Blending Options > Drop Shadow` and adjust the Blend Mode (set on `Multiply` by default), opacity, shadow color, contour etc.

Another way could be to duplicate the layer, set it in `Pin Light` mode, and again play with opacity. If the edges are too hard, you can use a `Gradient Overlay`, `Gaussian Blur` or simply erase the edges with the `Eraser` (soft brush, 30 to 50% opacity for softer results.)